# Extract specific data from line in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have one variable which contains many information and I want to extract some data from that line but not getting expected result.

Following is code

```
import re

line = "2019-08-10 00:57:24 [Thread-0] DEBUG CSConnection - Serial : LOG: ABC=1 XYZ=42 PQR=0015236800MOSAER"
result = re.search((r" (.*?):(.*?):"), line).group(0)
print(result)
```

Following output I am expecting

```
00:57
```

Following output I am getting.

```
 00:57:
```

What is missing to get the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a capture group around the pattern you want to extract:

```
result = re.search(r" (.*?:.*?):", line).group(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know what you are searching for always try to be as precise as possible. This will make it much more robust.

```
result = re.search(r"(\d{2}):(\d{2})", line).group(0)
```